# Calculate Distances Between One Point in Matrix From All Other Points

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am new to Python and I need to implement a clustering algorithm. For that, I will need to calculate distances between the given input data.

Consider the following input data -

```
    [[1,2,8],
     [7,4,2],
     [9,1,7],
     [0,1,5],
     [6,4,3]]
```

What I am looking to achieve here is, I want to calculate distance of [1,2,8] from ALL other points, and find a point where the distance is minimum.

And I have to repeat this for ALL other points.

I am trying to implement this with a FOR loop, but I am sure that SciPy/ NumPy must be having a function which can help me achieve this result efficiently.

I looked online, but the 'pdist' command could not get my work done.

Can someone guide me?

TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `np.linalg.norm` combined with broadcasting (*numpy outer subtraction*), you can do:

```
np.linalg.norm(a - a[:,None], axis=-1)
```

`a[:,None]` insert a new axis into `a`, `a - a[:,None]` will then do a row by row subtraction due to broadcasting. `np.linalg.norm` calculates the `np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(...)))` over the last axis:

---

```
a = np.array([[1,2,8],
     [7,4,2],
     [9,1,7],
     [0,1,5],
     [6,4,3]])

np.linalg.norm(a - a[:,None], axis=-1)
#array([[ 0.        ,  8.71779789,  8.1240384 ,  3.31662479,  7.34846923],
#       [ 8.71779789,  0.        ,  6.164414  ,  8.18535277,  1.41421356],
#       [ 8.1240384 ,  6.164414  ,  0.        ,  9.21954446,  5.83095189],
#       [ 3.31662479,  8.18535277,  9.21954446,  0.        ,  7.        ],
#       [ 7.34846923,  1.41421356,  5.83095189,  7.        ,  0.        ]])
```

The elements `[0,1]`, `[0,2]` for instance correspond to:

```
np.sqrt(np.sum((a[0] - a[1]) ** 2))
# 8.717797887081348

np.sqrt(np.sum((a[0] - a[2]) ** 2))
# 8.1240384046359608
```

respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It works great. Just one more question. To find the min distance between the point, I will have to eliminate the '0' from each row and find the min.

But, if there is a same point appearing more than once, then I have to treat it as two different points. So, I will have to reduce the a[i,i] as it will be zero, but I have to make use of the other '0'. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: A quick solution would be replace all the diagonals with `np.nan`, then use `np.nanmin` or `np.nanargmin`: `dist = np.linalg.norm(a - a[:,None], axis=-1); dist[np.arange(dist.shape[0]), np.arange(dist.shape[0])] = np.nan; np.nanargmin(dist, axis=0)`

Answer (score 8):

Here's one approach using [`SciPy's cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
def closest_rows(a):
    # Get euclidean distances as 2D array
    dists = cdist(a, a, 'sqeuclidean')

    # Fill diagonals with something greater than all elements as we intend
    # to get argmin indices later on and then index into input array with those
    # indices to get the closest rows
    dists.ravel()[::dists.shape[1]+1] = dists.max()+1
    return a[dists.argmin(1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [72]: a
Out[72]: 
array([[1, 2, 8],
       [7, 4, 2],
       [9, 1, 7],
       [0, 1, 5],
       [6, 4, 3]])

In [73]: closest_rows(a)
Out[73]: 
array([[0, 1, 5],
       [6, 4, 3],
       [6, 4, 3],
       [1, 2, 8],
       [7, 4, 2]])
```

**Runtime test**

Other working approach(es) -

```
def norm_app(a): # @Psidom's soln
    dist = np.linalg.norm(a - a[:,None], axis=-1); 
    dist[np.arange(dist.shape[0]), np.arange(dist.shape[0])] = np.nan
    return a[np.nanargmin(dist, axis=0)]
```

Timings with `10,000` points -

```
In [79]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,3))

In [80]: %timeit norm_app(a) # @Psidom's soln
1 loop, best of 3: 3.83 s per loop

In [81]: %timeit closest_rows(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 392 ms per loop
```

---

**Further performance boost**

There's [`eucl_dist`](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist)  package  (disclaimer: I am its author) that contains various methods to compute euclidean distances that are much more efficient than `SciPy's cdist`, especially for large arrays.

Thus, making use of it, we would have a more performant one, like so -

```
from eucl_dist.cpu_dist import dist
def closest_rows_v2(a):
    dists = dist(a,a, matmul="gemm", method="ext") 
    dists.ravel()[::dists.shape[1]+1] = dists.max()+1
    return a[dists.argmin(1)]
```

Timings -

```
In [162]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,3))

In [163]: %timeit closest_rows(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 394 ms per loop

In [164]: %timeit closest_rows_v2(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 229 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

[From this thread's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571624/sorting-points-from-distance-to-a-given-point-x-y-here-in-my-case-x-0-y-o/46574290#46574290)
you can use the **e_dist** function there and also obtain the same results.

**Addendum**

**Timing**:  on my memory starved laptop, I can only do a comparison to a smaller sample than @Psidom 's using his **norm_app** function.

a = np.random.randint(0,9,(5000,3))

%timeit norm_app(a)
1.91 s ± 13.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit e_dist(a, a)
631 ms ± 3.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
a 
array([[1, 2, 8],
       [7, 4, 2],
       [9, 1, 7],
       [0, 1, 5],
       [6, 4, 3]])

dm = e_dist(a, a)  # get the def from the link

dm
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  8.72,  8.12,  3.32,  7.35],
       [ 8.72,  0.  ,  6.16,  8.19,  1.41],
       [ 8.12,  6.16,  0.  ,  9.22,  5.83],
       [ 3.32,  8.19,  9.22,  0.  ,  7.  ],
       [ 7.35,  1.41,  5.83,  7.  ,  0.  ]])

idx = np.argsort(dm)

closest = a[idx]

closest
Out[10]: 
array([[[1, 2, 8],
        [0, 1, 5],
        [6, 4, 3],
        [9, 1, 7],
        [7, 4, 2]],

       [[7, 4, 2],
        [6, 4, 3],
        [9, 1, 7],
        [0, 1, 5],
        [1, 2, 8]],

       [[9, 1, 7],
        [6, 4, 3],
        [7, 4, 2],
        [1, 2, 8],
        [0, 1, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 5],
        [1, 2, 8],
        [6, 4, 3],
        [7, 4, 2],
        [9, 1, 7]],

       [[6, 4, 3],
        [7, 4, 2],
        [9, 1, 7],
        [0, 1, 5],
        [1, 2, 8]]])
```

Comment: I wasn't getting the expected results from your `closest` as I assumed the output would be of the same shape as the input - Each point would have one closest pt. So, I couldn't include yours in my timing results. Also, that `norm_app` is Psidom's.

Comment: corrected the name, thanks, I chose to sort the points rather than the results in case it was the point that was needed as well

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `pdist` and `squareform` from `scipy.spatial.distance`

Consider the following array of points:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,8], [7,4,2], [9,1,7], [0,1,5], [6,4,3]])
```

If you want to display **all distances** between point `[1,2,8]` and the other points:

```
squareform(pdist(a))

Out[1]: array([[ 0.        ,  8.71779789,  8.1240384 ,  3.31662479,  7.34846923],
               [ 8.71779789,  0.        ,  6.164414  ,  8.18535277,  1.41421356],
               [ 8.1240384 ,  6.164414  ,  0.        ,  9.21954446,  5.83095189],
               [ 3.31662479,  8.18535277,  9.21954446,  0.        ,  7.        ],
               [ 7.34846923,  1.41421356,  5.83095189,  7.        ,  0.        ]])
```

I you want to display the **shortest distance** between point `[1,2,8]` and the closest point:

```
sorted(squareform(pdist(a))[0])[1]

Out[2]: 3.3166247903553998
```

`[0]` being the index of your first point (`[1,2,8]`)

`[1]` being the index of the second minimum value (to avoid zeros)

If you want to display the **index** of the closest point to `[1,2,8]`:

```
np.argsort(squareform(pdist(a))[0])[1]

Out[3]: 3
```

Comment: Doesn't  `sorted(squareform(pdist(a))[0])[1]` calculate distance between all points ,to then only look at distances to [1,2,8] ? This seems to do a lot of unncessary calculus.