# Nearest Neighbor Search is too long for multiple datas

Tags: python, opencv, turtle-graphics, kdtree

Firstly, i have an image that I pass in arguments, and i retrieve all of his contours with OpenCV (with the `cv.findContours` method).
I parse this list with my `parseArray` method to have a well parsed list of x,y contours coordinates of the img `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]` (The size of this list equals `24163` for my unicorn image)

So here is my code:

```
def parseArray(array):
    parsedArray = []
    for i in array:
        for j in i:
            parsedArray.append((j[0][0], j[0][1]))
    return parsedArray

def delItemList(index, list):
    del list[index: index + 1]

img = cv.imread(sys.argv[1])

canny = cv.Canny(img, 215, 275)
contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(canny,cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
parsedArray = parseArray(contours)

drawList = []

while (len(parsedArray) > 0):
    tmp = [(0,0)]
    tree = KDTree(parsedArray)
    dist, ind = tree.query(tmp, k=1)
    tmp[0] = parsedArray[int(ind)]
    drawList.append(parsedArray[int(ind)])
    delItemList(int(ind), parsedArray)
```

And here is a `time` of this :

[image]

How can i reduce strongly the time of my loop (less than one second), is it possible?

Comment: profile your code. there can be no advice without facts.

Comment: I edited my question to focus on a single problem which is to reduce the execution time, you have everything at your disposal in terms of code, i hope that now you can give me advice because the facts are there ! @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: Why do you need your loop ? Can't you just use `tree.query([(0, 0)], k=len(parsedArray))` ? This will return all point from the closest to the farest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you spend most of your time in your while loop so I will focus on those lines:

```
while (len(parsedArray) > 0):
    tmp = [(0,0)]
    tree = KDTree(parsedArray)
    dist, ind = tree.query(tmp, k=1)
    tmp[0] = parsedArray[int(ind)]
    drawList.append(parsedArray[int(ind)])
    delItemList(int(ind), parsedArray)
```

My understanding is that you want to use a KDTree to find the nearest neighbor of the point [(0,0]] among the points of your contour and that once you find it, you remove it from the contour points and start again.
This is costly because you are creating a complex structure that is optimised to perform nearest neighbor query only for one query and then you create it again and again. I can suggest you two optimisations:

1. If you want to keep the KDTree for whatever reason, then query all the points at once: `tree.query(tmp, k=len(parsedArray))` (c.f. [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query))
2. Compute the distance between [(0, 0)] and each point of your contour and sort them by this distance. You can find solution for this on other thread such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636014/how-to-order-a-list-of-points-by-distance-to-a-given-point/30636138)